# Hashed Password Confirmation Error

Tags: java, mysql, hash, passwords

I am using Java Eclipse and hashing a password into a MySQL database. When a new user is created, I hash the password, then store it into the database. When the user logins, I hash the password, then compare it to the one on the database. However, I am printing the hashed password in both places and although I am entering the same original password in both instances, the hash value is different. Here is my hash function:

```
// hash the password to store in database
            String hashed_password = passwordField.toString();
            MessageDigest md = null;
            try {
                md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            md.update(hashed_password.getBytes());

            byte byteData[] = md.digest();

            //convert the byte to hex format method 1
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
             sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
            }

            System.out.println("Digest(in hex format):: " + sb.toString());
            // end of hashing
```

Here is my comparison:

```
String query = "select * from user where username=? and password=?";
                    PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                    pst.setString(1, userNameTextField.getText() );
                    //pst.setString(2 , passwordField.getText() );
                    pst.setString(2 , sb.toString() );

                    username = userNameTextField.getText();

                    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    int count = 0;
                    while(rs.next()){
                        count++;

                    }
                    if(count == 1){
                        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and password is correct");
                        listener.userLoggedIn(new UserAccount());
```

Comment: Where is your comparison code?

Comment: Also: Do not use a hash: A hash can be traced back to the original text for short texts like passwords. Use real encryption instead.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen that's bad advice. Real encryption needs a key, and anybody having the key can access all passwords. Hashes don't need a key, and nobody can reverse them, provided the algorithm is strong enough (MD5 is not) and the password is randomly salted.

Comment: I hope you're using a proper password hashing function and not something like MD5. I hope you're salting each password with a long and unique salt. Oh wait... Get rid of this code **immediately** and use [bcrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/).

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen no **no** **NO**. A thousand times no. This advice is extremely dangerous and completely incorrect. Please delete your commend and never advise anyone to do anything like that again. Ever.

Comment: I added in my comparison code

Comment: As mentioned above, all of this homebrew code is incredibly dangerous. It's a massive security vulnerability in you application. Please, for the sake of your liability insurance, delete it and use something designed for the task.